# DI Binding to a subclass

Tags: scala, scaldi

I'm wondering if it's possible to bind dependencies with following syntax:

```
bind [Environment[User, Authenticator]] to FakeEnvironment[User, SessionAuthenticator](testUser)
```

(this was taken from tests, actual binding in the Module is slightly more verbose)

where [SessionAuthenticator](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette/blob/master/app/com/mohiva/play/silhouette/impl/authenticators/SessionAuthenticator.scala) has following signature:

```
case class SessionAuthenticator(val loginInfo : com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.LoginInfo, ...)
    extends scala.AnyRef 
        with com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.Authenticator 
        with scala.Product 
        with scala.Serializable {...}
```

and [Authenticator](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette/blob/master/app/com/mohiva/play/silhouette/api/Authenticator.scala):

```
 trait Authenticator extends scala.AnyRef {...}
```

But all I get is the following stacktrace during compilation:

```
[error] /home/mironor/projects/livrarium/test/controllers/CloudSpec.scala:22: overloaded method value to with alternatives:
[error]   [T <: com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.Environment[services.User,com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.Authenticator]](fn: => T)(implicit evidence$2: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T])scaldi.BoundHelper[T] <and>
[error]   (none: None.type)scaldi.BoundHelper[com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.Environment[services.User,com.mohiva.play.silhouette.api.Authenticator]]
[error]  cannot be applied to (com.mohiva.play.silhouette.test.FakeEnvironment[services.User,com.mohiva.play.silhouette.impl.authenticators.SessionAuthenticator])
[error]       bind [Environment[User, Authenticator]] to FakeEnvironment[User, SessionAuthenticator](user)
```

This way I could choose which `Authenticator` to use **only once** in applicaiton's `Module` and inject it like this:

```
implicit val env = inject[Environment[User, Authenticator]]
```

instead of:

```
implicit val env = inject[Environment[User, SessionAuthenticator]]
```

What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to archive this with scaldi, but the problem is with the way `Environment` is defined and used. I assume (at least error tells me this) that `Environment` is invariant on both of it's type arguments. This is the problem, because you want to treat `Environment[User, Authenticator]` as a superclass of `Environment[User, SessionAuthenticator]`. It is not the case if both type arguments are defined as invariant. To fix this issue you can just make the second type argument of `Environment` covariant with `+`:

```
trait Environment[A, +B]
```

Theoretically it should fix the compile error you shown.

Comment: Thanks, that explains the problem, the trait is defined as trait Environment[I <: Identity, T <: Authenticator]